# Traitlets: Best way for a "Dict of Instance"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, traits

In my code, I need a `Dict` of `Instance` (for example a list of `Parameter` keyed by name). Currently I've solved this by using a regular `Dict`-traitlet as the incoming property (`parameters`) and then having a function that "translates" these into instances of the `Parameter` class.

Is there a better way to do this than:

```py
import traitlets as t
import traitlets.config as tc


class Parameter(tc.Configurable):
    name = t.Unicode().tag(config=True)
    description = t.Unicode(allow_none=True).tag(config=True)
    value = t.Any(default_value=None).tag(config=True)

class Job(tc.Configurable):
    parameters = t.Dict(allow_none=True).tag(config=True)
    _parameter_map = t.Dict()

    def init_parameters(self):
        self._parameter_map.clear()
        for name, configuration in self.parameters.items():
            configuration['name'] = name
            parameter = Parameter(**configuration, parent=self)
            self._parameter_map[name] = parameter
```

And then this:

```py
c.Job.parameters = {
    "parameter1": {
        "description": "The first parameter",
        "value": True
    }
}
```

It works and logic dictates that - since you configure by "class names" with the traitlets - it is the only way, but I just wanted to be sure